# Why is this template filter invalid?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter, django-template-filters

What am I doing wrong here?

I have roundnumber in a module called accounts_extras.py located in the templatetags directory.  In my template I have {% load accounts_extras %} at the top.  It's also worth noting that 'upto' is currently working in another template (haven't tried it on this template yet), but the issue is with roundnumber.  {{ staravg.stars__avg|roundnumber }} is giving me an invalid filter error.

```
#accounts_extras.py
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def upto(value, delimiter=None):
    return value.split(delimiter)[0]
upto.is_safe = True


@register.filter
def roundnumber(value):
    if value > 1.75 and value < 2.25
    return 2
    if value > 2.25 and value < 2.75
    return 2.5
    if value > 2.75 and value < 3.25
    return 3
    if value > 3.25 and value < 3.75
    return 3.5
    if value > 3.75 and value < 4.25
    return 4
```

Is the problem that I have two filters in the same module?  Is that allowed?

Comment: `roundnumber` has lots of syntax errors, please fix them first. Also, `value > 1.75 and value < 2.25` could be written as `1.75 < value < 2.25`

Comment: If you know you input value will always be between 1.75 and 4.25 then your `roundnumber` function could be rewritten as `return 0.5 * math.ceil(value * 2)`  If not, then you could store this value and if it beyond the bounds of 2 and 4 you could return whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter definition is fine. The problem is with the missing colons and indentation:

```
@register.filter
def roundnumber(value):
    if value > 1.75 and value < 2.25: # colon
        return 2 # indentation
    # ...
```